# Duas funções em um botão

Tags: php, jquery

Criei essa resposta para uma pergunta, ela funciona perfeitamente, insere no banco de dados e tudo. Queria só uma coisa, quando eu apertasse nesse botão ele além de salvar nesse banco de dados,também fosse para uma outra pagina onde tem outra pergunta.

```
if ($_POST['post'] == '3'){

   $db->query("INSERT INTO resp3 (id, tonemai)VALUE  (NULL ,'to nem ai, morra!')");
}
```

html

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="post" type="hidden" value="3"/>

    <input type="image" src="7.jpg" onclick="this.form.submit()" id="botao3">
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar o require("outra_pergunta.php"); após fazer a query, assim exibiria o conteúdo html de um arquivo chamado outra_pergunta.php que você tivesse no mesmo diretório do script atual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem como você está submetendo um formulário, o redirecionamento deve ser feito pelo *BackEnd* da sua aplicação (É possível fazer pelo *FrontEnd*).

Existem 2 formas de fazer o redirecionamento. A primeira é com o uso do método `header` em *PHP*.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

E o segundo é inserindo um *Script* em sua página.

```
echo "<script>location.href = \"http://www.example.com\"</script>";
```

> O primeiro método é mais recomendado, o segundo pode-se dizer que é um pouco de gambiara.

Comment: removi o comentário sobre a tag, pois já corrigi na pergunta.

Comment: vou tentar muito obrigado

Comment: Diego, muito obrigado, isso é para um projeto da minha faculdade que vai virar meu TCC se Deus quiser, e o senhor agora esta fazendo parte desse projeto com sua ajuda. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @JairoBorges, se a resposta resolveu seu problema, você pode clicar no **V** ao lado da resposta para indicar que o seu problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Lembre-se de fazer o redirecionamento antes de enviar qualquer dado para a página, para enviar os avisos de envio de cabeçalho